# Why is my simple use of shell-command to change a global keybinding in Linux not working?

Tags: string, shell-command, linux

I want to be able to change a global keybinding by calling an Emacs function.

The command in question is:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"`

This Linux shell command sets the keybinding for changing between applications.

When I call `shell-command` within Emacs and enter the above command, the expected result always happens: application switching becomes bound to Super-Tab.

The correct form for a simple shell-command is `(shell-command "command")`. I have successfully tested that this works by evaluating `(shell-command "ls")`.

However, when I evaluate the function

`(shell-command "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"")`

instead of this working as it does when I offer this string directly to shell-command prompt, I receive the error message: `eval-region: Invalid read syntax: "]"`.

I have tried every syntactic variation of this command that I can think of and read threads and blog posts discussing simple uses of shell-command, but I have found nothing applicable to this problem.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Just checking, but are you backslashing the double quotes? As in `(shell-command "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications \"['<Super>Tab']\"")`? Otherwise the string representing your command is ending prematurely at the first double quotes.

Comment: @kozina-adjacent: please make your comment into an answer. It is without a doubt the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When including double-quotes inside a string, be sure to "escape" them, which in Emacs is accomplished with a backslash, otherwise the string representing your command will end prematurely. (Well, at least earlier than you probably intended it to.) See [String syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Syntax.html#index-string-syntax) in the Emacs manual (or in Emacs: `C-h r i string syntax <RET>`).

In your case, the original command includes double-quotes:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"`

...which need to be backslashed in the string argument to `shell-command`:

`(shell-command "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications \"['<Super>Tab']\"")`

Comment: Thank you; this answer, as well as solving the problem, is something I didn't know that I didn't know.

Comment: @Orixi Glad I could help. By the by, you can access the Emacs manual in Emacs itself with `C-h r` (`C-h` is a prefix argument that directs to many help functions.) Once the Emacs manual is open, you can hit `i` to search for a topic like `string syntax`. And welcome to the forum and Emacs!

Comment: @Orixi Note that *literally every delimited format* (not only within Emacs) has this requirement if the delimiters themselves are to be allowed within the delimited text.  The concept of encoding a would-be special character to prevent it being special is known as "escaping" (not uncommonly using backslashes, but it varies).